# How to approach implementing a layout editor using Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos, layout, interface-builder

I want to build an OS X application, in which one of the requirements is for the user to be able to generate PDF output according to a layout that they, the user, will create.  Typical items on the page would be things like a corporate logo (a JPEG or PNG), an address (a block of text) and a narrative (another block of text).

I'd like the user to be able to move and resize the items using the mouse to drag handles around on-screen.

Is there an Interface Builder object that will let me do that, or some third-party library that exists for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Try [GCDrawKit](http://apptree.net/drawkit.htm) if you're looking for a drop-in solution. It's still in beta (and has been for ages) but you might find it useful.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Project got put on hold, so no progress or further investigation for now.  Thanks again, though.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for an all-encompassing, self-contained "Pages" control or some sort of reporting suite. That's asking a bit much.

There is nothing in the Cocoa frameworks that gives you this. Unfortunately, there's no Cocoa equivalent of Crystal Reports either. You'll have to roll your own.

I suggest using standard CSS / HTML templates with WebKit. The only drawback is WebKit doesn't yet support CSS pagination, so there's no concept of "8.5"x11" page 1...15" but it's the closest you'll come without writing your own Pages application (NOT an easy project by any stretch of the imagination).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll investigate further.